# Show/Hide Single Row in ASP.NET Repeater

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm having trouble showing just a single row inside a repeater. I have all of them expanding correctly, but my efforts to show just that row have not worked out well.

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptPlayers" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="DataBound_ItemDataBoundEvent">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <thead>
                    <tr>

                        <th>Name</th>

                        <th>Profile Approved?</th>
                        <th>Playing in <%: DateTime.Now.Year %>?</th>
                        <th>Roommate</th>
                        <th>Manage</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="#" class="show_hide"><%# Eval("FirstName") %>&nbsp;<%# Eval("LastName") %></a></td>
                        <td style="display: none"><%# Eval("PlayerEmail") %></td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkApproved" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("ProfileApproved") %>' /></td>
                        <td>

                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkPlayingCurrentYear" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("PlayingCurrentYear") %>' /></td>
                        <td>

                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRoommate" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True"></asp:DropDownList>&nbsp;
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAssign" runat="server" OnClick="AssignPlayer"></asp:LinkButton></td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="AdminActions" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                            <p class="text-danger">
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkApproveProfile" runat="server" OnClick="ApprovePlayer"></asp:LinkButton>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkConfirm" runat="server" OnClick="ConfirmPlayer"></asp:LinkButton>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                        <td style="display: none">
                            <asp:Literal ID="ltUserId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PlayerId") %>'></asp:Literal></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="6">
                            <div class="slidingDiv">
                                Fill this space with really interesting content. <a href="#" class="show_hide">hide</a>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

This is my current jQuery, what am I missing to just toggle a single row?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("div.slidingDiv").hide();
         $(".show_hide").show();
        $('.show_hide').click(function () {
            $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
           // $(this).next('div.slidingDiv').eq(0).slideToggle(800);


        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You'll need to clarify what you mean. You have three rows in your html (header row and two body rows). What row is it that you want to hide/show, what's the expected result? I can see that you toggle the last line, is this not working then?

Comment: Sorry, left out some details there. Clicking on the "FirstName" field in the first <td> will show/hide the <tr> that contains the div with the class "slidingDiv". So click on the name in the first <tr> will show the second <tr>. Right now all of them work at the same time, I was attempting to get them to function as a unit for each table row.

Comment: Good, then I guessed correct in my answer below (I think) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I need to take a best guess at what you want to do:

To make the jQuery toggle only the `slidingDiv` next to the row getting clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.slidingDiv').hide();
    $('.show_hide').show();
    $('.show_hide').click(function () {
        var x = $(this).closest('tr').next();
        x.find('.slidingDiv').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

This will not work for the link "*hide*" inside the content row. I suggest you use another class for that, lets call it `hideThis`, and do another script for that:

```
$('.hideThis').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('div').slideToggle();
});
```

Examples below:

```js
$('.slidingDiv').hide();
$('.show_hide').show();
$('.show_hide').click(function () {
    var x = $(this).closest('tr').next();
    x.find('.slidingDiv').slideToggle();
});

$('.hideThis').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('div').slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" class="show_hide">show hide</a>

        </td>
        <td style="display: none">dfhdhdh</td>
        <td>fgjfgj</td>
        <td>fgjhfj</td>
        <td>fgjfjfj</td>
        <td>fgjfjfjgfjfj</td>
        <td style="display: none">fgjfjgjfgjfjgf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6">
            <div class="slidingDiv">Fill this space with really interesting content. <a href="#" class="hideThis">hide</a>

            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" class="show_hide">show hide</a>

        </td>
        <td style="display: none">dfhdhdh</td>
        <td>fgjfgj</td>
        <td>fgjhfj</td>
        <td>fgjfjfj</td>
        <td>fgjfjfjgfjfj</td>
        <td style="display: none">fgjfjgjfgjfjgf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6">
            <div class="slidingDiv">Fill this space with really interesting content. <a href="#" class="hideThis">hide</a>

            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Might I also suggest that you move the `.slidingDiv` class to the `tr` instead of the `div`. As it is right now you're only hiding the div, but the row is still there (even if most browsers would show it with minimal height).

Comment: That fixed it up, I see where I was making my mistakes. Thanks for your help!